# Get Mouse Position on Canvas (But NOT on window)?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas, mouse, mouse-position

I have a project in WPF 4 and vb.net 2010.

I have a canvas inside a window. The window is full screen, but the canvas is set to a solid 640x480 in the center of the window. I need to get the mouse position inside of the canvas, but NOT inside of the window. How do I do this?

Comment: Erm, why not implement the canvas' MouseMove event?

Comment: Because events do not render values on their own, other than a boolean in some cases.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
```

> The position of the mouse pointer is
>   calculated relative to the specified
>   element with the upper-left corner of
>   element being the point of origin,

Comment: Hmm. Apparently is does after all, yet trying to use those (set as variables) to set the left and top properties of an object on the same canvas is not working...

Comment: Found the problem. Solution is in comments of accepted answer on this question:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659237/472647)

Answer (score 2):

Hi the important thing is the

> NOT on the Window

the canvas is part of the window as well.
one example:

- the Window.AllowsTransparency state is on true
- the Window.Background is #00000000 (completely transparent)
- the Window.Style is None
- the Window.State is Maximized and
- there are NO controls or elements on the window!

...
so if you start the application you will see Nothing
now tell me how to get the mouseposition on the screen in pixel

**!Warning!
if you juse `Mouse.GetPosition(this);` it will return x0 y0 every time**

Comment: yeah.. so what do I do if I need that ? in the window.MouseButtonUp event ?

Answer (score 1):

so I solved the Problem by using `System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition` it's a bit a mix of wpf and Windows.Forms but I've given up xD.

Sorry for yelling :/

To make it easy for me I made a Extension:

```
<DebuggerHidden> _
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Function toWfpPoint(p As System.Drawing.Point) As Point
    Return new Point(p.X, p.Y)
End Function
```

Now I just can juse it like this:

```
Dim MousPos As Point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.toWfpPoint
```